# How to differentiate between two different type of files in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I have a tool in which i save file in 2 formats (one is JSON and other is text(without extension)) and have 2 buttons for opening them.

In the upgraded version of tool, I have removed saving of text format. And now i don't want 2 buttons for loading 2 different files, i want both the files to be loaded with same button.

How this can be done because one file has ".json" extension and other file don't have any extension.

1 method i know is to check the file extension(is this standard way ?)

Any other ways ?

What is the pythonic way of doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can just check the extension. Use `endswith`

```
if filename.endswith('.json'):
    # it's json
else:
    # it's not
```

Or you could check the file contents itself.

```
s = open(filename).read()
try:
    json.loads(s)
    # it's json
except ValueError:
    # it's not
```

Comment: any other method (except checking file extension)

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches you can take:

---

use [`os.splitext`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to determine if the extension is `'json'`:

```
if os.splitext(path)[1] == 'json':
    ...
```

---

Or *try* to parse as `json`, parse the other way if that fails:

```
try:
    data = json.loads(contents)
except ValueError:
    data = parse_text()  # your custom function i guess?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
if os.path.splitext('file.json')[1] == '.json':
    #it's a json file
else:
    #it's not a json
```